# overloaded 'operator+' must be a unary or binary operator error

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

Following the advice [given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989127/what-do-i-often-see-references-in-operator-overloading-definitions/3989509#3989509), I have overloaded the `+` operator in my simple `Point` class as follows (the += overload works fine).

```
Point operator+ (Point p1, const Point& p2)
{
    return std::move(p1 += p2);
}
```

But I get an error saying

> overloaded 'operator+' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)

What is wrong?

Comment: The advice is wrong. [Never move return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion), this is a unnecessary code bloat and makes them even slower.

Comment: @ipc That was something else I was hoping to spark a little debate about

Comment: @ipc without a move that would have copied. He would have to split his code into two lines to achieve the same effect (it is not allowed to do NRVO from a function parameter, but the rvalue trasformation is still done).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yes, I need to `p1+=p2; return p1;` now, but I would also need to do the same with `move`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like you have declared your operator as a member function. A member function takes an implicit first parameter, meaning your operator now takes three parameters. You can fix this by making it a non-member function.

In any case, *it is preferable to declare it as a non-member*, to ensure symmetry between the LHS and the RHS of the operation.

As for [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move), it is in the `<utility>` header. Although I can't see the reason to use it here.

Comment: Well, the operators can be members but in this case the implicitly passed object counts as one argument already.

Comment: @DietmarKühl You're right, of course, they *can* be members, but better have symmetry between LHS and RHS.

Comment: Indeed it's generally considered best to have them as free functions, but you don't _need_ to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That overload of `std::move` is not relevant; the one pertinent here [is in `<utility>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Answer (score 17):

You want to do either:

```
// Member function, performs (*this + right)
Point operator+ (Point & right)
```

or

```
// Free function, performs (left + right)
Point operator+ (const Point &left, const Point& right)
```

Comment: What's the need for `friend` here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit a hack so you can declare the function inside the class declaration :-) Nothing to do with friendship.

Comment: I must add, I don't think `friend` is needed here at all, it is just confusing. Plus the signature change is significant here.

Comment: @juanchopanza declaring the function within a class implies access to private members.  That has already been done.  Using `friend` removes the implicit `this` from that situation.

Comment: But you don't need access to private members. Therefore, you shouldn't have any. Basic principles of encapsulation...

Comment: I think it was a programming error to declare it as a member. In any case, `+=` is usually public.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sure that you're right about that.  I think my answer directly answered the question with the least changes, but perhaps a note would have helped along the lines of "You should ask a new question about why this function should be declared outside of the class"

Answer (score 3):

You made the operator a member function, meaning it actually has three parameters when you include the implicit first `this` parameter.

Either:

- Use `*this` rather than `p1` and get rid of that first parameter, or
- Make the operator overload a free function (instead of a member) — this is preferred.

Comment: @ildjarn: Fracking oops. Ta :)